# What does "boy" mean here?

Tags: meaning, idioms, interjections

Recently, in a magazine, I read the following line:

> It's been an eventful year and boy, has it flown past!

My question is, what does the word "boy" mean here? Is it an idiom? What is its usage?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where did the interjections, "man!", "(oh) boy!", and "oh brother" come from, and why are they all male?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31519/where-did-the-interjections-man-oh-boy-and-oh-brother-come-from-an)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: This came before your linked question. Shouldn't the dupe go the other direction?

Comment: @Mitch: Yes, if you subscribe to the principle that "priority" goes to the first of related questions/answers. But I don't recognise that principle as appropriate here on ELU, whereas I *do* recognise that the top-rated answer here comes nowhere near answering the question as appropriately as the one on the later question. This one has just collected more votes because it's been here for a long time, but - no disrespect to Dusty - it's hardly a "canonical" answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`Boy` in this usage is an interjection that is an exclamation of surprise, wonder, contempt, etc.  In this particular sentence, it's just emphasizing how quickly the year has flown by.

You hear it pretty frequently in the "Oh Boy!" which used earnestly usually indicates excitement about something (or when used sarcastically, expresses dread).

`wow`, `golly` or `gee whiz` are similar expressions you might hear in these contexts as well. `crikey` fills the same function but is limited to UK/Australian English.

Comment: “Wow” also gets used much the same way, and “crikey” is very similar for UK/Aussie speakers.

Comment: Actually, more relevantly, *man* is also used somewhat similarly: “Man, that was awesome!”, or “Oh, man, this’ll be tough.”  *Dude* is maybe partway in drifting from a standard vocative to a having several interjective meanings, but (in the dialects I know) hasn’t come as far as *man* or *boy*, and its interjective senses have a slightly different feel — discussed much at http://tinyurl.com/2dqbeho Language Log.  I don’t know any feminine examples of this process, though for some speakers *dude* is pretty much gender-neutral.

Answer (score 2):

It's used to express surprise.

Other examples: 
Boy, was I wrong.
Boy, was it fun.

Boy, was it hard.

The above sentence conveys that you were surprised to see it was hard when you expected not to be.

Comment: Your answer would benefit from linked references to support your claim.

Answer (score 1):

A less common usage is "man."

"Man, this is great."

It is a way of addressing no one in particular.